# Where is HAProxy status ping on my EC2 instanstance coming from?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I setup a Linux instance on EC2 and opened up a TCP port at 8001.  I have an application listening on it for some custom raw data coming through.

In addition to that, however, I'm seeing:

GET /haproxy-status HTTP/1.0

pings coming through.  I cannot figure out what's doing it.  It seems to be coming from Amazon, but I cannot figure out what configuration is causing it.  I have no loadbalancers setup.

Any clue how to disable that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to find the source IP and block it?

E.g., using iptables:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -s IP.ADDRESS.HERE -j DROP
```